How to align commas when input is loaded from arrays
I have this simple table that loads its values from arrays defined in curly braces.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pgf}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\size}        {"101", "80", "95", "77"}
\newcommand{\minimum}     {"-7,6", "1,1", "-0,3", "1,5"}
\newcommand{\lowquantile} {"4,26", "5,21", "4,30", "3,20"}
\newcommand{\sd}          {"3,405", "4,123", "3,703", "0,244"}
\newcommand{\lowFence}    {"2,41", "3,10"}
\newcommand{\highFence}   {"4,09", "6,15"}

\newcommand{\tableValue}[2]{%
    \pgfmathparse{{#1}[#2]}%
    \mbox{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|p{3.5cm}|P{3cm}|P{3cm}|P{3cm}|P{3cm}|}
            \hline
            & \multicolumn{2}{P{6cm}|}{\textbf{Original}} & \multicolumn{2}{P{6cm}|}{\textbf{Without outliers}} \\ \hline
            & \centering \textbf{Setup A} & \textbf{Setup B} & \centering \textbf{Setup A} & \textbf{Setup B} \\ \hline
            size        & \tableValue{\size}{0}    & \tableValue{\size}{1}    & \tableValue{\size}{2}    & \tableValue{\size}{3}    \\ \hline
            minimum               & \tableValue{\minimum}{0}      & \tableValue{\minimum}{1}      & \tableValue{\minimum}{2}      & \tableValue{\minimum}{3}      \\ \hline
            q25         & \tableValue{\lowquantile}{0}       & \tableValue{\lowquantile}{1}       & \tableValue{\lowquantile}{2}       & \tableValue{\lowquantile}{3}       \\ \hline
            sd                & \tableValue{\sd}{0}   & \tableValue{\sd}{1}   & \tableValue{\sd}{2}   & \tableValue{\sd}{3}   \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{5}{|p{16cm}|}{\textbf{Fancy text to separate fences}} \\ \hline
            low fence   & \tableValue{\lowFence}{0} & \tableValue{\lowFence}{1} & \multicolumn{2}{P{6cm}|}{------------} \\ \hline
            high fence   & \tableValue{\highFence}{0} & \tableValue{\highFence}{1} & \multicolumn{2}{P{6cm}|}{------------} \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}%
    }
\end{table}

\end{document}

The rendered table looks like this:

As you can see the commas are NOT aligned but I need them aligned so that the table is more readable. Ideally the alignment of a column should look like this:
 101
-7,6
 4,26
 3,405
-------
 2,41
 4,09

What should I change to get this alignment?
